# When I call the clear method for a ListView object, the column headers disappear - VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, listview

Good day, I've just started teaching myself VB.net.  I'm trying to create a simple note keeping program.

I've come across a problem, where by I call the Clear method of the ListView object, and its column headers disappear.

[screen shot of what happens](https://i.imgur.com/RwC7s.png)

The code for button 2 is:

```
    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    lstNotes.Clear()
    End Sub
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `Clear` method on a listview does exactly that. Just as [advertised](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.clear.aspx).

Use `lstNotes.Items.Clear()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Augh, as luck would have it, I got the answer Just after posting.

lstNotes.Items.Clear()

Comment: Glad you found the answer! Please mark your answer as "accepted answer" (= click on the check mark), so that the question no longer shows up as "unanswered".

Answer (score 0):

use Items.clear() instead!

```
lstNotes.Items.Clear()
```